# Why are all badges not shown in profile badge tracking?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-bydesign, badges

I'm not able to see some badges in the profile badge tracking. For example, [Outspoken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731), [Tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399), [Enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), etc.

You can check by clicking on settings.

[image]

It will be helpful if clarified.

Comment: See also *[List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer on Meta Stack Exchange is, that not all Badges are trackable.

Most of the ones they don't show as trackable are those that tracking would impact performance.

[Here is the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253594#comment828208_253594) (*huge* page, careful it'll crash your phone browser) to the answer.