# Next available badges

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

When clicking on the wheel next to the current tracked badge, I can "choose which badge to track". Only a subset of the badges are available in that list (I see 42 badges in 'All').

- What is the rule that determines which badges are available here?
- If a user fulfills the requirement of a badge not on that list, will he still earns that badge?

EDIT:
the first question is answered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290396/why-all-badges-are-not-shown-in-profile-badge-tracking).

Comment: I think you see 100 badges, sorted by a combination of score and # of answers.

Comment: Actually I see less than that. Only 42 badges in 'All'.

Comment: Badge earning is not dependent upon the badge tracker in your profile, so qualifying for badges outside of the tracker will still net you those badges, such as a gold tag badge.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of that? Which badge could you have not being in the list? Notice that the tag badges are at a different location

Comment: For example "Unsung hero" is not in the list.

Comment: @DevShark I think they just show you the badges you can get through an achievment of your own. For `Unsung Hero`, you're not responsible for getting it. My 2 cents.

Comment: This is because some badges are left off for reasons dealing with the queries. There were a couple posts on MSE about this, I'll see if I can't find one or two of them.

Comment: Here we are, found a good one to answer your question: [Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263610/why-arent-all-the-badges-shown-on-the-track-menu) Seems like basically the same question you're asking here, really.

Comment: This other question answered half of my question (why it's not displayed). The other half of my question (will I still get awarded non-displayed flag) was answered by @TylerH .

Comment: @Maroun [Algorithm for sorting badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330614/917790)